# Bad Request on Embedded Console Sign View

Tags: docusignapi

I have gone past 2 stages in the Embedded Signing API which I use in my WCF web service using C#.

The login credentials & the request envelope API calls work & the envelopeID is generated.
The 3rd step is the "get URL for the Embedded Console Sign View"

```
string reqBody = "<recipientViewRequest xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                 "<authenticationMethod>" + "email" + "</authenticationMethod>" +
                 "<email>" + "jay.krishnamoorthy@gmail.com" + "</email>" +     // NOTE: Use different email address if username provided in non-email format!
                 "<returnUrl>" + "http://www.docusign.com" + "</returnUrl>" +  // username can be in email format or an actual ID string
                 "<clientUserId>" +  "1001" + "</clientUserId>" +
                 "<userName>" + "Jay Krishnamoorthy" + "</userName>" +
                 "</recipientViewRequest>";

// append uri + "/views/recipient" to baseUrl and use in the request
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseURL + uri + "/views/recipient");
request.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authenticateStr);
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.Accept = "application/xml";
request.ContentLength = reqBody.Length;
request.Method = "POST";
// write the body of the request
byte[] body2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqBody);
Stream dataStream2 = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream2.Write(body2, 0, reqBody.Length);
dataStream2.Close();
// read the response
webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();-----> comes back with Bad request
```

Can some one help with the missing info in my request body which causes the BAD request response.

Comment: When the webResponse fails it should send you to an exception block that will give you an error code and an error message.  Might help to grab that text and google for that specific error and/or include it in your question here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble making sense of the **reqBody** value in your question, so instead of commenting on that, I'll just provide a simple example of what a proper **POST Recipient View** request looks like (in XML format):

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/views/recipient

<recipientViewRequest xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <authenticationMethod>Email</authenticationMethod>
  <email>RECIPIENT_EMAIL_ADDRESS</email>  
  <returnUrl>http://www.google.com</returnUrl>
  <clientUserId>CLIENT_USER_ID_VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_THE_REQUEST</clientUserId>
  <userName>RECIPIENT_NAME</userName>
</recipientViewRequest>
```

I'd suggest that you compare the **request URI** and **request body** I've included here with what you're sending, and adjust yours as needed to match.

Additionally, I'd recommend that you use a tool like "Fiddler" or something similar to examine the XML Request and Response as they're being sent over the wire -- i.e., identify problems by examining the raw XML using Fiddler, then update your code to fix the problems (i.e., to generate/send a properly formatted request).  Being able to produce a trace of the raw XML Request / Response is a requirement of the DocuSign API Certification process, so you might as well figure that out sooner rather than later, as it's a valuable troubleshooting asset during development as well (when you get a "Bad Request" response like you're getting).

Answer (score 0):

Your request body has all the proper elements and looks to be correct on first glance, however I see what you are doing wrong now.  In your request body when you set the authentication method I see that you are setting it to:

```
"<authenticationMethod>" + "email" + "</authenticationMethod>"
```

This is incorrect.  The value here actually needs to be the string `email` or `Email`, you don't enter the recipient's actual email address.  The point of the `authenticationMethod` property is to tell the system what level of authentication you are expecting.  If set to `email` then you are telling the system simply that the email address is the only form of authentication you want for that recipient.  So what you want instead is:

```
"<authenticationMethod>email</authenticationMethod>"
```